# Problems searching for annotated classes using Reflections API

Tags: java, reflections

I'm having a very difficult time using the Reflections API to find classes that are annotated with a custom annotation at runtime. The ultimate goal is to find all classes in the project that are annotated with my custom @Job annotation, collect them, and allow each of them to be run from one location without adding each one to the page manually. However, I'm finding it extremely difficult to get the initial search to work correctly, so I cannot move on with my project.

My current approach is to use:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("jobs"))
        .setScanners(new TypeAnnotationsScanner())
        .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().includePackage("jobs")));
Set<Class<?>> jobs = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Job.class);
```

where "jobs" is the package containing all of the job classes that I am searching for, which will be annotated with the custom @Job annotation. "jobs" is a base package in my project, but the overall url on my machine looks something like ".../(project)/app/jobs". This setup results in one url being searched, which is ".../(project)/app/" with the additional filter "+jobs.*" in the configuration object. This seems like it is working correctly, but clearly something is wrong because I do not get any classes in the set.

If it matters, the annotation is coded as:

```
package jobs;
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Job {
    String description();
}
```

The annotation class is located within the same "jobs" package as the job classes I am searching for. An example of a job definition with the annotation included is:

```
package jobs;
@Job(description = "Description of what the job will do")
public class ExampleJob extends MasterJob {...}
```

I cannot find what I need to change in order to get this search to function as intended. Thanks for the help, and please let me know if I can clarify anything further.

EDIT: I believe the problem is associated with how the Play Framework loads its classes. Fortunately, the framework provides its own annotation search function, which I used instead. According to a comment, the code I have listed here will work, given that you have all the dependencies to run it. Feel free to use it as a template and let me know if it works for you as well.

Comment: I copied your code directly out of the report above and ran it; it ran successfully, identifying the annotated class correctly. I used the latest version of javassist.jar, guava-18.0.jar, and reflections-0.9.9-RC1-uberjar.jar. I ran the scanner from the default package, and both the annotation and my job class ("Ajob.java") in the "jobs" package.

Comment: @JerryAndrews Thank you for testing things out, I guess there seems to be something wrong outside of the code. I previously did not have javassist.jar included, but adding it as a dependency to my project did not fix the problem. I currently use guava 15.0, but updating this to 18.0 did not fix it either, and my reflections uberjar is current. For the sake of brainstorming, is it possible that renaming the original jar files has any effect on its usage? And do you think that this is a dependency-related issue? Also, the scanner is run from a file in app/folder1/folder2/Scanner.java. Thanks.